# error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] SwipeRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I have a problem with Dagger/MissingBinding.I have red all the related answers on stackoverflow. They didn't solve my problem.

Errors looks like:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] SwipeRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

And my sources:

**AppModule.kt**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttpClient(
        clientRequestInfo: ClientRequestInfo,
        sessionLocalDataSource: SessionLocalDataSource,
        loginLocalDataSource: LoginLocalDataSource,
        keyCheckerInterceptor: KeyCheckerInterceptor,
    ): OkHttpClient =
        OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(
                ClientAuthInterceptor(
                    clientRequestInfo,
                    sessionLocalDataSource,
                    loginLocalDataSource
                )
            )
            .addInterceptor(keyCheckerInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
            .build()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideClientRequestInfo(): ClientRequestInfo = ClientRequestInfo.Builder()
        .appName("twit")
        .versionCode("3")
        .rotalume(false)
        .Build()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(
        client: OkHttpClient, gson: Gson,
    ): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(LoginRetrofitService.ENDPOINT)
            .callFactory { client.newCall(it) }
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build()
    }
}
```

**SwipeModule.kt**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
abstract class SwipeModule {
    companion object {
        @Provides
        fun provideSwipeRetrofitService(retrofit: Retrofit): SwipeRetrofitService {
            return retrofit.create(SwipeRetrofitService::class.java)
        }

        @Provides
        fun provideSwipeRemoteDataSource(SwipeRetrofitService: SwipeRetrofitService): SwipeRemoteDataSource {
            return SwipeRemoteDataSource(SwipeRetrofitService)
        }

        @Provides
        fun provideSwipeRepository(
            SwipeRemoteDataSource: SwipeRemoteDataSource
        ): SwipeRepository {
            return SwipeRepositoryImpl(SwipeRemoteDataSource)
        }

        @Provides
        fun provideGetMatchUsersUsecase(SwipeRepository:SwipeRepositoryImpl): GetMatchUsersUsecase {
            return GetMatchUsersUsecase(SwipeRepository, Dispatchers.Default)
        }
    }

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindRepository(SwipeRepository: SwipeRepositoryImpl): SwipeRepository

}
```

**GetMatchUsersUsecase.kt**

```
class GetMatchUsersUsecase @Inject constructor(
    private val SwipeRepository: SwipeRepository,
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
) : FlowUseCase<String, SwipeResult>(dispatcher) {

    override fun execute(parameters: String): Flow<Result<SwipeResult>> {
        return flow {
            SwipeRepository.getMatchUsers().collect { result ->
                emit(result)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SwipeRepository.kt**

```
interface SwipeRepository {
    fun getMatchUsers(): Flow<Result<SwipeResult>>
}
```

and finally, my build.gradle files:

**build.gradle(Project)**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21-2"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha08'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.33-beta'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.twit"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 2
        versionName "0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        freeCompilerArgs += ["-Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies", "-Xskip-prerelease-check"]
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion "1.4.21-2"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.0.0-alpha11"
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.2"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.33-beta"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.33-beta"
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha03'
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
}
```

So, please tell me any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: So basically, you're trying to inject `SwipeRepository` into `GetMatchUsersUsecase` right?

Comment: Yes, exactly it is. I'm provide this class. But i am getting this error

Comment: Ok. Then try out my answer and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is usage of binds and provides together.

From the docs here: [https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/faq.html#:~:text=Because%20%40Binds%20methods%20are%20just,implementation%20and%20will%20be%20invoked](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/faq.html#:%7E:text=Because%20%40Binds%20methods%20are%20just,implementation%20and%20will%20be%20invoked).

> **Why can’t @Binds and instance @Provides methods go in the same module?**
>
> Because @Binds methods are just a method declaration, they are
> expressed as abstract methods — no implementation is ever created and
> nothing is ever invoked. On the other hand, a @Provides method does
> have an implementation and will be invoked.
>
> Since @Binds methods are never implemented, no concrete class is ever
> created that implements those methods. However, instance @Provides
> methods require a concrete class in order to construct an instance on
> which the method can be invoked.

**Solution:**

If you want to use both in the same module. Use bind inside an interface. Like below.

```
@Module(includes = [SwipeModule.Test::class])
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object SwipeModule {


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesRepo(): SwipeRepository {
        return SwipeRepositoryImpl()
    }

    @Module
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    interface Test{
        @Binds
        fun bindRepository(SwipeRepository: SwipeRepositoryImpl): SwipeRepository
    }

}
```

Try this way and let me know.

Comment: Thank you for answer. This answer is solved my problem. But I have another question for you. Why did you use **@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)** besides **@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)** ? When I use **@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)** in your response, i get the same error

Comment: @tametahh I was able to use  `ActivityComponent::class` in my example. It works for me. But maybe there is something else in your project that's causing this issue. Like inside `SwipeModule` it does not make sense to use `provideSwipeRepository` and `bindrespository` both because `provideSwipeRepository` is sufficient as it implements SwipeRepository.  `bindrespository` might not be needed at all. Please check and let me know.

Comment: I removed the `bindRepository` and i added `ActivityComponent::class` as you said. It didn't work. I got same error.

Comment: @tametahh Well. Then it's something else. For now you can move with the answer that works for you. But, I would suggest you read more about components here: https://dagger.dev/hilt/components  to get the idea what may be the issue.